# Azure Web App Service - How to force non WWW to go to WWW?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App on the Standard App Service. I am able to access the site by going to http://www.websitename.com but unable to access the website via http://websitename.com.

How can I get the web address with the non www. to go to the www. version?

In my DNS Configuration for the domain my A Name record is pointing at the IP Address of the Web App in Azure, and the CName record at the Azurewebsites.net domain.

Comment: have you tried this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/10/01/mapping-a-naked-url-to-your-azure-web-site-url-with-no-www.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Azure portal, you will need to add both `www.websitename.com` and `websitename.com` as host names for the Web App, so that Azure knows to send traffic to it.